# Insertar índice de una variable en una tabla

Tags: php, sql

Quisiera saber cuál es la forma correcta de insertar el índice de una variable dentro de una tabla.
tengo un código en el que inserto una variable que puede tener hasta índice 29 (su índice no siempre llega al 29) , pero parece que no lo hago de la forma correcta, pues no se inserta nada..

Dejo mi código por si me pueden ayudar y de antemano gracias!

```
 $fecha_trash = explode (",",$resultados_trash[0]);//separo por comas el array de todas las fechas intermedias ( puse $resultados_trash[0] porque el explode no funciono sin indicar el indice. Al indicar el indice 0, tomo toda la cadena de fechas)


         <?php$insercion = mysqli_query($conexion2, "INSERT INTO $nombre_tabla (usuario,fecha1,fecha2,inter1,inter2,inter3,inter4,inter5,inter6,inter7,inter8,inter9,inter10,inter11,inter12,inter13,inter14,inter15,inter16,inter17,inter18,inter19,inter20,inter21,inter22,inter23,inter24,inter25,inter26,inter27,inter28,inter29,inter30) values ('$varsesion','$fecha1','$fecha2','".$fecha_trash[0]."','".$fecha_trash[1]."','".$fecha_trash[2]."','".$fecha_trash[3]."','".$fecha_trash[4]."','".$fecha_trash[5]."','".$fecha_trash[6]."','".$fecha_trash[7]."','".$fecha_trash[8]."','".$fecha_trash[9]."','".$fecha_trash[10]."','".$fecha_trash[11]."','".$fecha_trash[12]."','".$fecha_trash[13]."','".$fecha_trash[14]."','".$fecha_trash[15]."','".$fecha_trash[16]."','".$fecha_trash[17]."','".$fecha_trash[18]."','".$fecha_trash[19]."','".$fecha_trash[20]."','".$fecha_trash[21]."','".$fecha_trash[22]."','".$fecha_trash[23]."','".$fecha_trash[24]."','".$fecha_trash[25]."','".$fecha_trash[26]."','".$fecha_trash[27]."','".$fecha_trash[28]."','".$fecha_trash[29]."')"); ?>
```

Comment: Te marca algún error?

Comment: Hola  Sr1871, ya note que no es la forma en que escribo el código. 
El problema esta en mi variable  $nombre_tabla. No se por que no esta recogiendo el nombre de la tabla. En fin jajaja igual gracias por comentar

Answer (score 0):

Vi que al parecer ya resolviste tu problema, pero estaba redactando algo que a lo mejor te sirve para manejar los indices dinámicos en las consultas. 
Mencionas que los datos que tiene el array `$fecha_trash[x]` que hay que insertar en la tabla es variable. 
Sin embargo, hay información que no especificas, como por ejemplo, si la cantidad de datos del array tienen que ser consecutivos o no. Para ilustrarlo:

```
// Consecutivo
$fecha_trash = array(inter1, inter2, inter3,... inter24, inter25);
// No consecutivo
$fecha_trash = array(inter1, inter2, inter7,... inter22, inter26);
```

Asumiendo que el array ese tiene un índice numérico consecutivo, y para que funcione bien el `explode`, que la variable tiene el formato:

```
$resultados_trash = array("fecha1,fecha2,fecha3,...", "otra_cadena...");
```

Entonces una forma de crear un query de inserción dinámico es la siguiente:

```
$fecha_trash = explode (",",$resultados_trash[0]); 
$subquery1 = "";
$subquery2 = "";
$i = 1;
foreach($fecha_trash as $value) {
    $subquery1 .= ", inter" . $i;
    $subquery2 .= ", '$value'";
    $i++;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO $nombre_tabla 
(usuario, fecha1, fecha2 $subquery1) 
VALUES 
('$varsesion', '$fecha1', '$fecha2' $subquery2)";

$insercion = mysqli_query($conexion2, $query);
```

O si quieres incluir siempre los 29 elementos, si el motor de base de datos es MySQL o MariaDB, se puede hacer algo como esto:

```
$fecha_trash = explode (",",$resultados_trash[0]); 
$subquery1 = "";
$subquery2 = "";
for($i=0; $i<29; $i++) {
    $subquery1 .= ", inter" . ($i+1);
    $subquery2 .= isset($fecha_trash[$i]) ? ", '$fecha_trash[$i]'" : ", NULL";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO $nombre_tabla 
(usuario, fecha1, fecha2 $subquery1) 
VALUES 
('$varsesion', '$fecha1', '$fecha2' $subquery2)";

$insercion = mysqli_query($conexion2, $query);
```